# How can I un-check "Coming events from Evolution Calendar" in Time & Date?

Tags: indicator, evolution, 16.10, calendar

I would like to un-check the following option to show events from Evolution calendar in the time & date indicator but it is grayed out. Evolution is not installed on my system.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: What implication that option has on your system?

Comment: Please see my update.

Comment: Do you have Evolution installed?

Comment: No. Thus I don't expect this option to appear in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indicator regarding your question is called `indicator-datetime`, the following command should disable showing upcoming events:

`gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime show-events false`

This setting could also be found via `dconf-editor`, which i can only recommend as it has a search option.