# Is it possible to show Evolution Calendar Events in applet or indicator using MATE Panel?

Tags: indicator, mate, evolution, calendar, applet

As long time Ubuntu user I remembered how this was realized in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
It had `indicator-datetime` and showed calendar events from GNOME Evolution (connected to some CalDav server or used local calendar). The needed applet should look like

[image: screenshot 2]
(from [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/q/847139/66509))

How to get this functionality in the modern MATE desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible in Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS and newer versions.

We need to install `indicator-datetime` and GNOME Evolution with

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime --no-install-recommends
sudo apt-get install evolution
```

Then set up calendar account in Evolution (E-Mail, Contacts and **Calendar** here) and ensure that the calendar is visible.

Note: if we are running Ubuntu MATE 18.10 or 19.04, then we need to install GNOME Calendar with
`sudo apt-get install gnome-calendar --no-install-recommends` before proceeding.

Start the indicator manually for the first time with:

```
systemctl start indicator-datetime.service --user
```

Then we will see the second clock (provided by `indicator-datetime`) with calendar in the MATE Panel:

[image: calendar]

To make it start on every boot we need to add this line to the *Startup Applications* (`mate-session-properties`) or set it with programmatical way:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart/
cat << EOF > ~/.config/autostart/indicator-datetime.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=systemctl start indicator-datetime.service --user
Hidden=false
X-MATE-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=indicator-datetime
Name=indicator-datetime

EOF
```

All we need is to rearrange MATE Panel to have single clock and other indicators in place.
Really we need to remove right *Clock* applet.
The result will look like:

[image: clock]

and clock will have the needed calendar.

---

For Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS see [other answer with hacky method](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145083/66509).