# Is it possible to run some application in the chroot or container but allow DBus interaction with host system?

Tags: 16.04, mate, lxc, chroot, lxd

I need to run old version of application in `chroot` (or container) and allow DBus interaction with host system. I can't install this application on host system because of serious dependency problems.

Full details about applications:

- application to be containerized is GNOME Evolution version 3.2.3  (from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
- the host system is Ubuntu **MATE** 16.04 LTS, it will run back-ported `indicator-datetime-gtk2`, which communicates with containerized Evolution through D-BUS.

I hope that it is technically possible with `schroot`'s bind mounts or LXC/LXD.

How should I set up such configuration?

Comment: @N0rbert, have you tried mounting DBus  `mount -o bind /var/run/dbus/ /path-to-newroot/var/run/dbus/` , probably need to copy `/etc/passwd` also to get Evolution run using same user as parent environment. reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebootstrapChroot

Comment: @user.dz Great idea, thanks! I have tried it, but it does not work - I do not see interaction between evolution (chroot) and applet (host). Maybe I wrongly understand how they work :(

Comment: @N0rbert , I'm limited right now in Internet access to download both packages and check their dbus service files. However, the expected setup is that evolution create and own the DBus master address, the applet connects to that address. You may use `d-feet` tool to check if evolution dbus is active, if it is ok, restart applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Difficulties using `indicator-datetime-gtk2` (from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS with GNOME Evolution

The MATE DE 1.12.1 uses GTK2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, so the `indicator-datetime-gtk2` itself may be ported from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and shown in `mate-indicator-applet`, but the integration with modern GNOME Evolution will not work because of seriously changed API.

The usual GTK3-based `indicator-datetime` or [its UBports' fork](https://github.com/ubports/indicator-datetime) will not integrate to GTK2-based `mate-indicator-applet`.

The DBUS LXC/LXD solution seems to be not applicable to current problem. There is something wrong with bus-addressing or service naming.

## The solution for Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS

I found only one hacky solution for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS MATE - to install Xfce4 panel and add `indicator-datetime` applet to it with:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-datetime evolution
sudo apt-get install xfce4-panel xfce4-indicator-plugin --no-install-recommends
```

along with runnable MATE panels.

And configure the added Xfce4 panel with the below options:

1. Choose *One empty panel* on first launch
2. Right click on the panel, select *Add New Items*
3. Search for *Indicator Plugin* and add it
4. Move Xfce4 Panel to the top right corner, *Lock panel* it and set to auto-hide (*Automatically hide the panel:* → *Always*)

To have `xfce4-panel` shown on each boot I have added it to startup applications:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
cat <<EOF > ~/.config/autostart/xfce4-panel.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=xfce4-panel &
Hidden=false
X-MATE-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=xfce4-panel
EOF
```

and optionally set `indicator-datetime` to 24-hours format with:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format '24-hour'
```

which gives nice looking auto-hiding syncable calendar indicator:

> - calendar is hidden [image: xfce4-panel with indicator-datetime - hidden]
> - calendar is shown [image: xfce4-panel with indicator-datetime - shown]
> - GNOME Evolution opened - [image: GNOME Evolution with event]

Comment: Although my uneventful life doesn't require a calendar, yours looks really cool +1. PS I deleted my comments under your question above. Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following guide on how to

1. create a system container with some old version of Ubuntu (like 12.04 or 14.04), and
2. set it up so that you can run GUI programs from within that system container and get the output on your host

See guide from https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/ .

The guide has an example on running some old Tcl/Tk utility in a Ubuntu 12.04 system container.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your guides. Could please clarify one moment before I'll follow them? Do I need special settings for **D-Bus** intercommunication between container and host system?

Comment: For D-Bus, you need to additionally share the D-Bus socket from the host to the container. On Ubuntu 18.04, the socket file is `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`. You should be able to figure it out since the guide already shows how to do the X11 socket and the PulseAudio socket. I'll be willing to add D-Bus to the tutorial once you do it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not so familiar with lxd config. Could you please share working solution? I'll open bounty reward for this question soon. Just curious, will we have problems with `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variable?

Comment: Simos, thank you for your help. With your great guides now I know what is LXC / LXD and how to use them.

Comment: Please reproduce at least some of the content from your guide here. We require that answers are actually answering the question. You are just giving a link to where an answer can be found. A very useful link, but still a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `indicator-datetime` [version for 16.04](https://launchpad.net/indicator-datetime) which ***may*** work for you. Development seems to have stalled working on the 16.10 version however it may work for you under 18.04.